# Getting problems while showing map from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

My app is getting crashed when I rotate my tablet from portrait to landscape mode and here is the stack trace.

```
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3273)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3291)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3489)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1280)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1291)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PhotosFragment.onDestroyView(PhotosFragment.java:144)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1596)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1017)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1826)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5171)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1109)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
04-13 16:06:25.802: E/AndroidRuntime(6231):     ... 12 more
```

I am using navigation drawer in my project . In drawer i have a list which on clicking opens fragment. In that fragment i am using map. The xml of map is made by using fragment tag in xml.

This is my fragment code 
p

```
ublic View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.currentmap)).getMap();
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);               


         // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
        }

       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        return rootView;
    }
     private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
         String strAdd = "";

         try {
             List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
             if (addresses != null) {
                 Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                 StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                 for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                     strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                 }
                 strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                 tvLocation.setText(strAdd);    
                 Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
             } else {
                 Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
         }
         return strAdd;
     }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        tvLocation = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();     

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        getCompleteAddressString(latitude,longitude);


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {

        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Log.v("in on destroy","destroy");

        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.currentmap));  
        if (fragment != null){
            Log.v("in on destroy","removing");
          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .remove(fragment)
            .commit(); 
            Log.v("in on destroy","completed");
            }      

       Log.v("value is", val+"");
}
}
```

This problem is only coming on maps fragment. Other fragments on which I haven't used map are working fine for orientation changes

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917), insert this code:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
}
```

Comment: in fragment or in activity? since i took one activity(having drawer layout) and fragment is having map

Comment: i guess `Fragment` is the one that handles the rotation in your app

Comment: still getting same exception

Comment: either if you put it in the activity?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the MapViews lifecycle calls:

Add this to your code:

```
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

@Override

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false)
mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.currentmap);

try {
     MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
     mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
       //Google play services not availabe
    }
if(mapView!= null){



googleMap = mapView.getMap();
}
```

//your code here

}

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mapView!=null)
    mapView.onResume();

}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mapView!=null)
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mapView!=null)
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

Use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as a parent of your mapview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/currentmap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: currentmap is fragment id  not mapview

Comment: you can put  your mapview insede a LinearLayout or a RealtiveLayout:

Comment: i dont think it has anything to do with linear layout. The thing is we need to save the state of map on orientation changes and i am not getting how to do so in my condition. I guess its answer is not in SO. Seen many questions like this but none is answered well

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution . I need to add this in manifest

```
<activity 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="MyFragmentActivity" 
        android:label="@string/fragmentActivity" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
```